# PHP (ZLIB) uncompression of a C (ZLIB) compressed array returns gibberish

Tags: php, c, encoding, compression, zlib

I have a set of ZLIB compressed / base64 encoded strings (done in a C program) that are stored in a database. I have written a small PHP page that should retrieve these values and plot them (the string originally was a list of floats).

Chunk of C program that compresses/encodes:

```
error=compress2(comp_buffer, &comp_length,(const Bytef*)data.mz ,(uLongf)length,Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION); /* compression */
if (error != Z_OK) {fprintf(stderr,"zlib error..exiting"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
mz_binary=g_base64_encode (comp_buffer,comp_length); /* encoding */
```

(Example) of original input format:

```
292.1149    8379.5928
366.1519  101313.3906
367.3778   20361.8105
369.1290   17033.3223
375.4355    1159.1841
467.3191    8445.3926
```

Each column was compressed/encoded as a single string. To reconstruct the original data i am using the following code:

```
//$row[4] is retrieved from the DB and contains the compressed/encoded string
$mz = base64_decode($row[4]);
$unc_mz = gzuncompress($mz);
echo $unc_mz;
```

Yet this gives me the following output:

```
f6jEÍ„]EšiSE@IEfŽ
```

Could anyone give me a tip/hint about what I might be missing?

------ Added Information -----

I feel that the problem comes from the fact that currently php views $unc_mz as a single string while in reality i would have to re-construct an array containing X lines (this output was from a 9 line file) but... no idea how to do that assignment.

The C program that did that went roughly like this:

```
 uncompress( pUncompr , &uncomprLen , (const Bytef*)pDecoded , decodedSize );
 pToBeCorrected = (char *)pUncompr;
 for (n = 0; n < (2 * peaksCount); n++) {
    pPeaks[n] = (RAMPREAL) ((float *) pToBeCorrected)[n];
 }
```

where peaksCount would be the amount of 'lines'  in the input file.

---

**EDIT (15-2-2012)**: The problem with my code was that I was not reconstructing the array, the fixed code is as follows (might be handy if someone needs a similar snippet):

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $m< = base64_decode($row[4]);
    $mz_int = gzuncompress($int);
    $max = strlen($unc_mz);
    $counter = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i = $i + 4) {
      $temp= substr($unc_mz,$i,4);
      $temp = unpack("f",$temp);
      $mz_array[$counter] = $temp[1];
      $counter++;
    }
```

The uncompressed string has to be chopped into chunks corresponding to the length of a float, unpack() then reconstructs the float data from teh binary 'chunk'. That's the simplest description that I can give for the above snippet.

Answer (score 1):

compress2() produces the zlib format (RFC 1950).  I would have to guess that something called gzuncompress() is expecting the gzip format (RFC 1952).  So gzuncompress() would immediately fail upon not finding a gzip header.

You would need to use deflateInit2() in zlib to request that deflate() produce gzip-formatted output, or find or provide a different function in PHP that expects the zlib format.

Comment: I figured out where I made the mistake, gzuncompress is correct however in this context. gzdecode() is the function that expects a gzip compressed file. I will append my 'fix' to the original question (basically I assumed that the function would reconstruct the array for me).

Comment: I found some php documentation, and I see that you're correct. Someone came up with horribly misleading names for the gzcompress and gzuncompress functions, as well as gzdeflate and gzinflate. None of them operate on the .gz format!